# Number of Deformation Parameters of Simple Polyhedron Equals Number of Edges

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, deformation-theory

Suppose $P$ is a simple convex polyhedron with $n$ faces. Euler's formula and the handshaking lemma tell us that the number of edges $E=3n-6$. By a *deformation* of  $P$, I mean a polyhedron, combinatorially equivalent to $P$, resulting from slightly perturbing the $n$ planes defining $P$. (Since $P$ is simple, any sufficiently small perturbation of faces preserves the combinatorial type.) Let's say two deformations are the same if there is a Euclidean isometry taking one to the other. A perturbation of each plane is given by 3 parameters (normal and position), and the Euclidean group is 6 dimensional. I believe this means that the space of deformations of $P$ is $(3n-6)$-dimensional—that is, $E$-dimensional. So, a deformation of $P$ is determined by one real parameter for each edge of $P$.

What could this parameter possibly be? Clearly not dihedral angle, as scaling is a non-trivial deformation which preserves all angles. Taking $P$ to be the prism of a rhombus, as suggested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311584/342007), demonstrates that it can't be edge length. But these two quantities are the only geometric properties of an edge that I can think of. Perhaps this is just a complete coincidence? Or perhaps my dimension argument is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5812) might contain some useful references. The introduction confirms your computation and points to an older proof by Legendre.

Comment: The article seems to imply that the result—i.e., that the deformation space is $E$-dimensional—holds for any polyhedron, not just simple or simplicial ones. Is that right?

Comment: You are right, but I have no immediate idea for how to generalize my answer to match this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple polyhedra might not be uniquely determined by the lengths of their edges, but *simplicial* polyhedra (all faces are triangles) are. This follows essentially from Cauchy's rigidity theorem.

The polar dual $P^\circ$ of your simple polyhedron $P$ is simplicial, and each edge of $P$ corresponds to an edge of $P^\circ$. If you assign to each edge $e\subset P$ the length of the dual edge, then this allows for a unique reconstruction. Simply reconstruct the dual from the edge lengths, and then dualize to obtain $P$.

There is one subtlety, in that the dualization process depends on the position of the polyhedron relative to the origin. So let us choose a conanical point for dualization, say, the average of all vertex coordinates. Put this point into the origin and you get a unique correspondence between $P$ and $P^\circ$.

The real number that you assign to each edge of $P$ in this way is not "obvious" from a visual inspection of the polyhedron, in contrast to edge length or dihedral angles. It not only depends on the edge $e$, its location or the incident faces, but on a full tubular neighborhood of $e$. But as you have seen, this complexity would have vanished if you instead would have considered simplicial polyhedra.